# how to detect if a specific block has been broken with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an arena in my world and I can't figure out how a command block can detect if the spawner is broken then send a redstone impulse. Please help me.

Comment: With ˋ/execute if blockˋ? Or do you want to differentiate breaking, pushing with piston, exploding, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

`/execute unless block [coordinates of spawner] spawner run setblock [coordinates of where to send the redstone signal] redstone_block`